# how to embed a c library in android

Tags: java, android, c++, c

I have an iphone app. I made my source code as boost library. Is there any possibility to embed my library to my android app? I am using eclipse. Can any one send any link about this.

At least a simple C or C++ library embedding to android and using those functions in my android app?

Comment: Android NDK allows you to implement parts of your app in C/C++ http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.I will respond after I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Android NDK tool chain for cross compiling the library. This link shows how to use it -

"http://www.cmumobileapps.com/2011/08/31/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-1/"

If you need support of STL, RTTI, C++ exception, then there's a patched up NDK available at http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r4.php

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.I will respond after I achieve this

Comment: But I am a windows user.The link explains for ios and linux

Comment: Does it really matter? If you're using windows then you must be using Cygwin, where you can find all the necessary tools, cmds.